# What is the default value for PHP `error_reporting`?

Tags: php, documentation, default, error-reporting, php-8

I know what the [`error_reporting` values mean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#refsect1-function.error-reporting-examples). I know `-1` means "show all" and `0` means "show none".

But nowhere is specified what is the value set by default, when nothing is specified by the user.

Trying `phpinfo()` I see

```
...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
...
```

So, given there's no `php.ini` loaded, **what is the default value/behaviour of `error_reporting`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of the [config file options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

> The default value is `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`. This setting does not show `E_NOTICE`, `E_STRICT` and `E_DEPRECATED` level errors. You may want to show them during development.

In PHP 8.0, the default changed to `E_ALL`. See https://php.watch/versions/8.0/error-display-E_ALL

Comment: You can read all about it here : https://php.watch/versions/8.0/error-display-E_ALL

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.3 or newer versions but prior to PHP 8.0, the default error_reporting level was:

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
>
> This means that all type of errors are reported except E_NOTICE,
> E_STRICT, and E_DEPRECATED.

Since PHP 8.0, the default error_reporting level is E_ALL.

> error_reporting = E_ALL

Have a look:  https://lindevs.com/default-error-reporting-level-is-e_all-in-php-8-0/